# How to remove category or product or blog from url through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Example
www.abc.com/product/my-products/345 to www.abc.com/my-products/345

Or

www.abc.com/category/category_name to www.abc.com/category_name

Answer (score 1):

All chars (.*) after /product/ or /category/ redirect to /chars with status HTTP 301

> `RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteRule ^product\/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
>   RewriteRule ^category\/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: It would be best to give a description along with the code to explain what it does.